# How do I set a route as an Index if it requires a parameter

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I was following the [quick start guide](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview#index-routes) on react-router, and I came across this code sample that shows how to direct a route to a nested route by default using `index`.

Now my question is if the path you're trying to switch to requires a parameter `:someID` how would I set it as the index with a default value? e.g `/23`

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
        <Route index element={<Activity />} />
        <Route path="invoices" element={<Invoices />} />
        <Route path="activity" element={<Activity />} />
        <Route path=":someID" element={<SomePath />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

Comment: If an index route has any path parameters they will have been defined in the parent `Route` component's `path` prop. An index route is only a route whose path is the same as the parent route. What exactly is the issue you have? Do you have a better code example for what you are trying to accomplish? Is the code snippet your code or code from the docs/guide?

Comment: ```<Routes>
        <Route path="/:category" element={<Main />} />
    </Routes>
```
take this code block as an example. If this is the only page in my app, I would like to set it to show different categories at the click of a link. How do I set the default category to show when the app starts?
@DrewReese

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly now, you are asking how to default your app to a specific URL path. For this you can render a redirect to the `"/:category"` route with *some* default value, i.e. `<Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/defaultCategory" replace />} />` when the app mounts and the URL path isn't already a match for the category route.

Example:

```
import { Routes, Route, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

...

<Routes>
  <Route path="/:category" element={<Main />} />
  <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/foo" replace />} />
</Routes>
```

Another method would be to have the `App` component issue an imperative redirect to a default category value. This requires `App` to have a router higher than it in the ReactTree so `App` can access the routing context it provides.

Example:

```
import { Routes, Route, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const App = () => {

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    // redirect to default category when `App` mounts
    navigate("/foo", { replace: true });
  }, []);

  return (
    ...

    <Routes>
      <Route path="/:category" element={<Main />} />
    </Routes>

    ...
  );
}
```

...

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <App />
</BrowserRouter>
```